# DocX clone table and insert at index

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

I am using C# to make a simple Windows app using Novacode to manipulate a Word document.

I have a source table in my Word document that I want to clone.  I am able to find the source table okay using this code:

```
Table sourceTable = document.Tables[3];
```

I can see by the rows and columns that this is in fact the table that I want to clone.

I have a string in my Word doc that right after it I want to insert my cloned source table.  In fact, I may need to insert it more than once.

I don't know how to find my string, the index of it, and then insert the one or more cloned tables at that index.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I do it, I use a tag that I insert and replace with table:

```
// Add a Table to this document.
var table = document.AddTable(2, 3);

// Specify some properties for this Table.
table.Alignment = Alignment.center;

// Add content to this Table.
table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("A");
table.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("B");
table.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("C");
table.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("D");
table.Rows[1].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("E");
table.Rows[1].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("F");

// Insert table at index where tag #TABLE# is in document.
document.InsertTable(table));
foreach (var paragraph in document.Paragraphs)
{
    paragraph.FindAll("#TABLE#").ForEach(index => paragraph.InsertTableAfterSelf((table)));
}

//Remove tag
document.ReplaceText("#TABLE#", "");
```